# C #Define into Function

Tags: c, function, c-preprocessor

I currently want to substitute defines with a function

Here's the define

```
#define f_rn(bo, bi, n, k)  do {                \
bo[n] = crypto_ft_tab[0][byte(bi[n], 0)] ^          \
    crypto_ft_tab[1][byte(bi[(n + 1) & 3], 1)] ^        \
    crypto_ft_tab[2][byte(bi[(n + 2) & 3], 2)] ^        \
    crypto_ft_tab[3][byte(bi[(n + 3) & 3], 3)] ^ *(k + n);  \
} while (0)


#define f_nround(bo, bi, k) do {\
    f_rn(bo, bi, 0, k); \
    f_rn(bo, bi, 1, k); \
    f_rn(bo, bi, 2, k); \
    f_rn(bo, bi, 3, k); \
    k += 4;         \
    } while (0)
```

I would like to have them in functions instead of defines.

Here's the snippet which calls the defines:

```
f_nround(b1, b0, kp);
f_nround(b0, b1, kp);
```

and my idea was to do the following

```
void enc_round(uint32_t b0[4], uint32_t b1[4], const uint32_t *kp)
{
for (int n = 0; n<4; n++)
    {
    b0[n] = crypto_ft_tab[0][byte(b1[n], 0)] ^
        crypto_ft_tab[1][byte(b1[(n + 1) & 3], 1)] ^
        crypto_ft_tab[2][byte(b1[(n + 2) & 3], 2)] ^
        crypto_ft_tab[3][byte(b1[(n + 3) & 3], 3)] ^ *(kp + n);
    }
kp += 4;
}
```

but this didn't work out as expected as the results are now false.

Any advice how to do this properly?

Comment: `kp += 4;` should probably be `*kp += 4;`. Similarly, `*(kp + n)` should maybe be `*(*kp + n)`, though it's hard to tell out of context.

Comment: Do you know how functions work and how macros work?

Comment: Assuming this is slurped from [`aes_generic`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/crypto/aes_generic.c#L1307), `kp` should be a reference to a pointer, not just a pointer (ex: `const uint32_t *& kp`). The syntax for the pointer math at-first-glance looks correct.

Comment: `kp += 4` is pointless. It only changes a local copy inside the function. You need to pass a **`uint32_t **`** if you want the changes to have effect outside the function.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That's not C, though.

Comment: @NisseEngström fair enough. double indirection ftw (+1 to your answer btw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> kp += 4;
> ```

This line is useless (inside the function). It only changes a local copy of the pointer. If you want the pointer to change outside the function, you need to pass the address of the pointer:

```
void enc_round(uint32_t b0[4], uint32_t b1[4], const uint32_t **kpp)
{
  for (int n = 0; n<4; n++)
  {
    b0[n] = crypto_ft_tab[0][byte(b1[n], 0)] ^
            crypto_ft_tab[1][byte(b1[(n + 1) & 3], 1)] ^
            crypto_ft_tab[2][byte(b1[(n + 2) & 3], 2)] ^
            crypto_ft_tab[3][byte(b1[(n + 3) & 3], 3)] ^ *(*kpp + n);
  }
  *kpp += 4;
}

uint32_t *kp;
/* ... */
enc_round(b0, b1, &kp);
```

**Or**, you could change `kp` after you have called the function.